# PIR Wall Switch Occupancy Sensor not working WSP-250

Tags: walls, switch, motion-sensor

Good evening. My wall switch went from not working at all to now staying on. I removed it from the wall and it is now working but won’t shut off. I can hear something rattling on the inside as we were having to use a pencil to turn it off and on. Should I just replace the switch as I think the sensor is bad. Thank you as any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What make and model is said occupancy sensor?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the directions state that the use of a pencil is the proper way to operate the switch, you should replace it. The rattling sound would also be a reason for replacement. Don't chance it arcing because the internal contacts aren't connecting right. Take some pictures of the switch before disconnecting any wires. That way we can better assist you if you have some trouble. Many questions on this site are because someone disconnected something and cannot remember how to reconnect it. Pictures are worth a thousand words. turn off the breaker to the circuit before doing anything. Good luck.

Comment: Without knowledge of electronics, you might be able to purchase a soldering iron and parts to repair this but asking this kind of question I would say purchase a new one , then if you find help online repair it and you will have a spare for when the other one fails.